Modelling investments in double entry bookkeeping
I'm building an app where users can buy and sell investments – imagine Robinhood or Freetrade. My app uses APIs to manage the money and trades and isn't the ultimate source of truth for balances, but I want to implement a ledger system so that I have an internally consistent view of a customer's funds at any given time as the money moves between accounts.
I'm using a fairly standard data model with accounts and transactions, similar to this gist.
My question is about how to represent investments (which can rise and fall in value) in a ledger (which is all about keeping value constant). I understand that the book value is only updated when the customer sells their investments, but which account does the growth (or loss) come from?
For example:

Customer adds money to their app account
amount: $100 from: customer_payable to: cash_account

Customer buys a share for $50
amount $50 from: cash_account to: investment_account

Customer sells their share for $55
amount: $50 from: investment_account to: cash_account
amount: $5 from: ????? to: cash_account


Which account does that $5 growth come from?
